# SQL Injection in a Web Service URL as a Parameter Value

Tags: database, web-services, rest, url, sql-injection

Obviously SQL Injection via the payload of a message is a very common practice and therefore it is always key to cover this (I already have in my code). However I'm just wondering about how possible it is for SQL Injection via the URL and whether this is possible as an actual method for SQL Injection.

I'll give an example URL to detail my question better. If I have a URL such as this with the SQL statement to be used for Injection included inside a parameter as its value (please note that the 'SELECT' could be any SQL query):

https://testurl.com:1234/webservicename?parameter=SELECT

I would like to know if this is valid way and would this actually work for hackers in terms of trying to inject into the back-end of the desired web service and also if so, what is the best way to go about covering for this?

Comment: The simplest way to avoid SQL injection is to [use parameterized stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parameterized+stored+procedure+sql+injection) and don't be concatenating or trusting any input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same things as for the POST datas. If it's in php, you get your value in $_GET['parameter']. You can after that secure the value before building your SQL request. Usually, you will also need to put quotes to end the string value and write your own request. GET method is not safer than POST data, never trust datas coming from the client side. It all depend on how you secure that datas. If it's well secured, hacked can't broke anything (by this way), if it's not well or not secured at all, an hacker can inject his requests.